# How to fix NullPointerException in Java?

Tags: java

I'm creating a math program that asks the user how many digits they'd like to use, then asks them what kind of math they want to do. It then asks the user 10 math questions based on their answers. It then decides if they're right or wrong and displays an appropriate message. It then calculates their percentage of correct answers and displays a message based on the percentage.

I seem to have the math logic working, but as soon it loops into the second question, I get a NullpointerException.

I've never run into this issue before, but what I gathered from searching around is that it means that I'm trying to use an object that has a null value (not 100% on this?). 
Can anyone tell me why this code would work fine the first time around, but then throw this exception the second time around?

Thanks for any help.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at assignment2.Assignment2.askQuestion(Assignment2.java:104)
>       at assignment2.Assignment2.main(Assignment2.java:43)

Line 104 reads

```
operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)] : operators[selectedOperator - 1];
```

Line 43 reads

```
   askQuestion(0, null, 0, 0, null, 0);
```

Full code

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Problem2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int difficulty = 1;
        String[] operators = {"plus", "minus", "times", "divided by"};
        int selectedOperator = 1;
        int correctAnswers = 0;
        int answeredTyped = 0;

        int difficultyInput = Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose the difficulty. " +
                    "Enter the number of digits to use in each problem."));

        if (difficultyInput > 0) {
            difficulty = difficultyInput;
        }
        int arithmeticMethod = Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Choose an arithmetic problem to study: 1 " +
                "= Addition Only, 2 = Subtraction Only, 3 = " +
                "Multiplication Only, 4 = Division Only, 5 = Random Problems" ));

        selectedOperator = arithmeticMethod;

        new Problem2().askQuestion(difficulty, null,
                    arithmeticMethod, arithmeticMethod,
                                operators, arithmeticMethod);

        while(answeredTyped < 10) {
            askQuestion(0, null, 0, 0, null, 0);
            if(((float)correctAnswers / answeredTyped) >= 0.75) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Congratulations, you are ready to go on to the next level!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "Please ask your teacher for extra help.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkResponse (double primaryInt,
            double secondaryInt, String operatorText, double response){
        if (operatorText.equals("plus")) {
            return (primaryInt + secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("minus")) {
            return (primaryInt - secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("times")) {
            return (primaryInt * secondaryInt) == response;
        } else if (operatorText.equals("divided by")) {
            return (primaryInt / secondaryInt) == response;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String displayResponse (boolean isCorrect) {
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1);
        switch (randomIndex) {
            case 1:
                return isCorrect ? "Very Good!" : "No. Please try again.";
            case 2:
                return isCorrect ? "Excellent!" : "Wrong. Try once more.";
            case 3:
                return isCorrect ? "Nice Work!" : "Don\'t give up!";
            case 4:
                return isCorrect ? "Keep up the good work!" : "No. Keep trying.";
        }
        return "Oops...";
    }

    public static void askQuestion(int difficulty,
            String operatorText, int selectedOperator,
                int answeredTyped, String[] operators, int correctAnswers){
        boolean correctAnswer = false;
        double primaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10,
            difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty-1));
        double secondaryInt = Math.floor(Math.pow(10,
            difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty-1));
        operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)] : operators[selectedOperator - 1];

        while(!correctAnswer && answeredTyped < 10) {
            double response = Double.parseDouble (
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is " +
                    primaryInt + " " + operatorText + " " + secondaryInt + "?"));
            correctAnswer = checkResponse (primaryInt,
                    secondaryInt, operatorText, response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayResponse(correctAnswer));

            answeredTyped++;

            if(correctAnswer)
                correctAnswers++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *How to fix NullPointerException in Java?* By making sure the variable is not `null` when being used. Check your code in Assignment2.java file, line 104 to check which variable was `null` and start debugging.

Comment: Do read what causes NPE and it will make life easy for you.

Comment: @Prateek IMO the name of the exception is self explanatory :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah I know but I have came across a number of similar questions on SO in recent past. In most of the cases the OP doesn't know why NPE do occur hence my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`askQuestion(0, null, 0, 0, null, 0);`

All the parms to the static method askQuestion are null/zero, including "operators".  There's no way for "operators" to NOT be null when you get to that squirrely assignment to "operatorText".

Comment: What could I change "null" to on that line to use the string/array? Eclipse automatically corrected my code to "null" for both of them and I really don't know what other options I can use.

Comment: @user2774647 - You coded it (sorta) correctly a few lines up.  (Though why you do a `new` there I haven't a clue.)

Comment: I've changed the code to 
askQuestion(difficulty, operatorText, selectedOperator, answeredTyped, operators, correctAnswers);

However, "operatorText" is still says it cannot find variable "operatorText". Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually I figured it out! Thank you very much. And as usual, as soon as I fixed one problem, now another one arises. Never stops at 10! Guess I have some more work to do haha

Comment: @user2774647: also work on your code formatting. If your code isn't formatted well, you will make stupid mistakes, and then if you post it here, we will struggle to understand it. 1+ To Hot Licks.

Comment: Will do, I'm very new to Java so this is all still a bit confusing. Now that this error is fixed, the program shows "Please ask your teacher for help" after the second question (no matter how many right/wrong), and doesn't stop at 10. It's a never ending problem! lol

Comment: @user2774647 : The `answeredTyped` belongs local to the method main, and it's not been assigned the new incremented value which it gets inside `askQuestion` method, so either __return__ this value and store it back in the `answeredTyped` variable or use `answeredType` variable as instance variable, instead of `Local`, and bring all logic part outside `main`. `main` is basically used to start the application, not to work on the application.

Comment: @nIcE cOw : How exactly do I go about returning the answeredTyped variable to the main method so it will assign it the new incremented value? Thanks a ton for your help. I am new to this so it is pretty confusing!

Comment: @user2774647 : Simply write `int` in place of `void` as `askQuestion`'s return type  and write `return answeredType` as the last line of `askQuestion` and inside the main use `answeredType = askQuestion(...)`. THat will suffice. If you really don't know these thingy, it's much better to stop know, and learn the basics, before you move ahead. No point in moving forward, with what knowledge you possess at this stage. Learn the basics right of the language.

Comment: @user2774647 : It seems like, you have to return `correctedAnswers` too from the same method. It would be wise, if you create all instance variables, instead of being local to the main.